# Delete a join table entry from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup a delete link for a join table entry.

I have a `@miniatures` model which has_many `@lines` through the `@minilines` join table.

On my `@miniatures` show page I call the associated `@lines` with

```
<% @miniature.lines.each do |line| %> 
    <%= link_to line.name, line %>
<% end %>
```

That all works fine. All associations correct etc. What I'm trying to do is add a little delete link. It's currently as follows

```
<% @miniature.lines.each do |line| %> 
    <%= link_to line.name, line %>
  <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'.html_safe, miniline_path(:miniature_id => @miniature.id, :line_id => line.id),
            :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %><br />
<% end %>
```

In my mini lines_controller I have the following destroy action

```
def destroy
    Miniline.find_by_miniature_id_and_line_id(params[:miniature_id, :line_id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Miniature removed from product line."
    redirect_to :back
end
```

It's currently returning `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your routes and controllers setup correctly, you can type rake routes in terminal and check out the delete path for minilines. You can send the miniature and line model with the path. Then in the controller, instead of finding by id. you can do something like this MiniLine.find_by_miniature_id_and_line_id(miniature.id, line.id), then destroy the result.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I want. I've updated my question with the results of rake routes. Do I then just need to route to 'miniline'?

Comment: Yeh. Just send the model and line with it and you can access them in the controller through the params hash. Then use the find method I wrote above to find the join table entry you're looking to destroy.

Comment: I've updated my question with the error I'm now getting trying to implement your suggestion.

Comment: When you pass the miniature and line through the delete request you need to create the params hash. miniline_path(miniline, :miniature_id => @miniature.id, :line_id => line.id). Then on controller side you can find those values like this params[:miniature_id]

Comment: Ok, getting warmer. I've updated my question with current error.

Comment: Miniline.find_by_miniature_id_and_line_id(params[:miniature_id], params[:line_id]).destroy Try this.

Comment: Bingo! Should I accept your answer or do you want to update it? Now I just need to make the redirect_to work once the assoc is deleted.

Comment: Fixed that too. Great great great.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can just accept my answer. I got to go right now anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for this .

```
<%= f.fields_for :lines, :wrapper => false do |task_form| %>
    <tr class="fields">
      <td><%= task_form.text_field :name %></td>
      <td><%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this line" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I can see how that simplifies the destroy link but I can't see how that helps me get to the join object in the above instance.

Comment: That looks like it will delete the `@line` rather than the joining `@miniline`, no?

Comment: are you not trying to delete miniature's lines ?

Comment: I'm trying to delete the association, which is an entry in @minilines.